# How to create fixed text position

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have image at button background, and button title text which some times are overlaps image.

[image]

You can see at the pictures, my question is do swift have some possibility to make border for text?

I mean in place where i have green icon text will not overlaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **`titleEdgeInsets`** property for this purpose,

For now i have kept 5 pixels in the left, you can increase if you want more

```
myButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

I was able to get padding around the text, effectively making the frame bigger, by doing:

```
myButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,5,5)
```

Comment: try to increase the left inset and see, or else, please paste your UIButton code in your question for reference.

Comment: i change right value, and this working, but text is not in the center

Comment: then dont use contentEdgeInsets, use only titleEdgeInsets